Minimum of $\frac{f(x)}{x^{n+1}}$ is at end point?
Let $f:[0,1)\to \Bbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Impose the following conditions on $f$:
$1. f(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = 0$.
$2. f'(x) = 0$ only for specific $x_1, x_2 \in [0,1)$ with $f(x_1)$ being a local maximum and $f(x_2)$ being a local minimum. Moreover, $x_1 < x_2$.
$3. f$ is real-analytic.
Let $n\in \Bbb{N}$ be the smallest positive integer such that $f^{(n)}(0) \ne 0$. Then, for $0<y\leq x_2$,
$$
\min_{0<x\leq y} \frac{f(x)}{x^{n+1}} = \frac{f(y)}{y^{n+1}}.
$$
Any counter-examples that would be nice, or if a simple proof is known that would be even better.
